# Unable to Include '.inc' files in x86 Assembly (TASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

```
include 'graphfun.inc'
include 'movesfun.inc'
include 'bmpfun.inc'
include 'iofun.inc'
include 'sfx.inc'
```

I am trying to include these files in my main .asm but an error occurs "Can't locate file: graphfun.inc"

Comment: Those libraries are not shipped with TASM. Ask the person who told you to use them, where you can obtain them.

Comment: Chances are you'll have to have them in the same folder where the file you're trying to compile is. I'm not sure how your assembler works but when I do `include` statements I can put the full file path (e.g. `include "C:\Users\Me\Documents\x86_Assembly\graphfun.inc"` and it will work. Do you use Notepad++?